# View PDF not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, pdf

I'm writing a static resume page using AngularJS. I want the user to click on my CV, a PDF, and be able to view it in the browser. My code works in Firefox, but when I test it in Chrome, I just get a black screen. It appears to be opening, but doesn't display the file.
The path to the PDF is specified in my controller and I've written a directive to display the link in my HTML.

Controller:

```
app.controller('webCV', function($scope) {

 $scope.links = [{
  text: 'Github',
  link: 'https://github.com/a-person'
 },
 {
  text: 'Resume',
  link: '../CV.pdf'
 },
 {
  text: 'Contact',
  link: 'mailto:a.person@gmail.com'
 }]
})
```

Directive HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in info">
 <a href="{{ x.link }}" target="_blank">{{ x.text }}</a>
</div>
```

What's a reliable cross-browser way of opening a PDF file as an `<a href>` link?

I assume this can be done without extra libraries and plugins like PDF.js so I'd rather not use them.

I've been stuck on this for ages so thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not an angular expert, but shouldn't it be `x in links` ?

Comment: @tapananand I'm not an expert either but it works fine. `info` refers to the `$scope.links` array in the controller and `x.link` iterates over each link value in the three objects.